# pvcreate not working: can't open exclusively

Tags: raid, lvm

After having added 2 disks of 1Tb to a Dell PowerEdge, I went through their initialization with the goal to add them to an existing LVM VG.

When the MegaCli background initialization went complete, I did fdisk the new disk to add a Linux LVM partition on it.

Then, pvcreate refused to work:

```
pvcreate  /dev/sdn1
  Can't open /dev/sdn1 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

Part of strace of the pvcreation:

```
open("/dev/sdn1", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_DIRECT|O_NOATIME) = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

Of course, the device is NOT mounted nor used: (fuser reports nothing).

Any idea why this is blocked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe device-mapper is 'stealing' this device. Try this:

```
[root@host ~]# dmsetup ls
sdb     (253, 2)
VolGroup00-LogVol01     (253, 1)
VolGroup00-LogVol00     (253, 0)
```

If you find sdb device listed as above example, remove it using dmsetup and create the physical volume:

```
[root@host ~]# dmsetup remove sdb

[root@host ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb
Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created
```

Comment: Copy-pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11477042 (it's your own post, but readers have to know about copy-paste).

Comment: you use lsblk and blkid to identify who is  using /dev/sdn1